# javascript countdown timer with button to add 10 seconds to the timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, progress-bar

hi I am not able to do timer with increase 10 sec button. I am trying since 2 days and I watched tutorials and read posts but no use please help me with this . it should look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e26EQ.png).
I tried this but no use I didn't come up  with any solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.